# How to hide managed package test-only Custom Metadata records once the package is installed?

Tags: configuration, custom-metadata

The advice in [Testing Custom Metadata Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/05/testing-custom-metadata-types.html) is to add metadata records for unit tests if necessary. We need our managed package customers to be able to add additional records, so having the test-only records visible to them is going to be a bit confusing and inelegant.

Is there a way to hide or (automatically) remove these test-only records so they are not there in orgs into which the managed package is installed?

Comment: Not really; I'd say best practice would be to set up your code in a way that you can mock metadata records. Also, I think in Summer 18 we can insert metadata records in Apex Code?

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks. Unfortunately the Apex insertion is async and doesn't work in tests. Would like to avoid mocking because a fairly complex query is used and I want to test that too.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there's a way to have your cake and eat it, too, though I'd love to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply make the records protected. Then subscribers won't be able to see them.

Or do you mean they need to be hidden from your *own* application outside of test contexts? I covered that case in a blog pose [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/05/testing-custom-metadata-types.html) (see the section "Testing Global Custom Metadata").

Comment: I'll just add to this - I added an "isTest" Boolean field (but omitted it from the MDT page layout) because SOQL doesn't yet support querying whether a record is Protected. I only ever query the MDT using a dedicated class. The class is configured that in unit tests it queries only `isTest = true` records, and outside of unit tests it queries only `isTest = false` records.

Comment: Its the subscribers I want to hide them through so cool, thanks.

Comment: @CharlesT Also my colleague suggested making the IsTest field protected to hide that from the subscriber org.